# Input NaN in Vue3?

Tags: javascript, typescript, vue.js, vuejs3

There is a formula that calculates the margin. My problem here is that when I do not enter a number, the NaN value is returned in the z value.How can I remove NaN and leave it blank?
[image]

Template

```
      <form>
        <div class="row">
          <div class="mb-3 col-sm-4 col-xs-12">
            <h6 class="text-dark" for="purchasePrice">x:</h6>
            <input
              type="text"
              class="form-control"
              autocomplete="off"
              v-model="purchasePrice"
              @keypress="isNumber($event)"
            />
          </div>
          <div class="mb-3 col-sm-4 col-xs-12">
            <h6 class="text-dark" for="salePrice">y:</h6>
            <input
              type="text"
              class="form-control"
              autocomplete="off"
              v-model="salePrice"
              @keypress="isNumber($event)"
            />
          </div>
          <div class="mb-3 col-sm-4 col-xs-12">
            <h6 class="text-dark" for="marginResult">z:</h6>
            <input
              type="text"
              class="form-control"
              autocomplete="off"
              disabled
              :value="
                (
                  ((parseInt(salePrice) - parseInt(purchasePrice)) /
                    parseInt(salePrice)) *
                  100
                ).toFixed(3)
              "
            />
          </div>
        </div>
      </form>
```

Comment: Doing all this inside the template is a bad idea; you should do it in your code. Then you can easily do `:value="isNaN(val) ? '' : val"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the comment suggest you you should try like this below code is working as you expected.

```
     <template>
      <form>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="mb-3 col-sm-4 col-xs-12">
        <h6 class="text-dark" for="purchasePrice">x:</h6>
        <input
          type="text"
          class="form-control"
          autocomplete="off"
          v-model="purchasePrice"
          @keypress="isNumber($event)"
        />
      </div>
      <div class="mb-3 col-sm-4 col-xs-12">
        <h6 class="text-dark" for="salePrice">y:</h6>
        <input
          type="text"
          class="form-control"
          autocomplete="off"
          v-model="salePrice"
          @keypress="isNumber($event)"
        />
      </div>
      <div class="mb-3 col-sm-4 col-xs-12">
        <h6 class="text-dark" for="marginResult">z:</h6>
        <input
          type="text"
          class="form-control"
          autocomplete="off"
          disabled
        v-model="marginResult"
        />
      </div>
    </div>
  </form>
```

```
<script>
 export default {
  data() {
  return {
  purchasePrice: '',
  salePrice: '',

   }
  },

  methods: {
    isNumber(e) {
    if (e.keyCode < 48 || e.keyCode > 57) {
        e.preventDefault();
    }
    }
    },

computed: {
    marginResult() {
        return (this.salePrice - this.purchasePrice).toFixed(2);
    }
},

}
</script>
```

[Screenshot for you to check if code works or not](https://app.usebubbles.com/iYx1RXCMUMX2UzVYq873Pf/stack-answer)

opp's your are expecting blank it returns 0.00 but you get the idead.

Comment: thanks for answer but ı have some problem. Yes your formula in computed works but  when ı write different formula like `((salePrice-purchasePrice) / salePrice) * 100` i see same problem, same NaN. Can you help? Thanks in Advance

Comment: okay let me  check

Comment: i guess i got NaN cause in formula blank divide blank gives the NaN

Comment: yeah. in your computed method implement (:value="isNaN(val) ? '' : val") from above comment will solve the current issue with the formula.

Comment: or  computed:{
        marginResult() {
            const res= (((this.salePrice-this.purchasePrice) / this.salePrice)  * 100) .toFixed(2) ;
            if(isNaN(res)){
                return 0;
            }
            return res;
        }
    },

Comment: I applied your second answer and it works very well at the beginning, but when I enter the first input and do not enter the second input, I see -infinity. How can I solve this.Btw thank you for your interest <3

Comment: if(isNaN(res) || res == '-Infinity'){
                return 0;
            } just update your condition